# lucene *.cfs numbers growth

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net, full-text-indexing

After every update of index in lucene *.cfs file number growth _2.cfs, _5.cfs, _7.cfs.
Every time. Is it ok or maybe I forgot to close some objects in code or else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that this is OK, if you execute $index->optimize() after updating your index. Otherwise it is also OK, but the quality of your index begins to corrupt.

Comment: Thanks, I call optimize and have only one file, but it's name changed every time with incrementing number.

Comment: that's OK. The thing with the incrementing number is unimportant

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you need to Optimize the index, it has its advantages,

1) .CFS(Compound file) are merged into one big Segment file

2) MergeFactor is also a criteria why you have so much compound files, set it to something around 15-20, we have found it giving good results in that range with decent memory usage